# (lldb) error with no comment after passing information with second segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "DeckViewSegue" {
            let navigationViewController: DeckViewNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as DeckViewNavigationController
            let deckViewMenu: DeckViewMenu = navigationViewController.viewControllers[0] as DeckViewMenu
            let nameOfDeck = currentDeckName
            deckViewMenu.currentDeckName = nameOfDeck
        }
        if segue.identifier == "DeckTestSegue" {
            /*
            let navigationViewController: DeckTestNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as DeckTestNavigationController
            let deckTestMenu: DeckTestMenu = navigationViewController.viewControllers[0] as DeckTestMenu
            let nameOfDeck = currentDeckName
            deckTestMenu.currentDeckName = nameOfDeck
            */
            println("DeckTestSegue Success") // This still prints in the console
        }
}
```

The code above compiles fine and when the second segue is clicked the console prints out: `DeckTestSegue Success`

But the problem arises when the chunk of code that is passing the information is uncommented:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "DeckViewSegue" {
            let navigationViewController: DeckViewNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as DeckViewNavigationController
            let deckViewMenu: DeckViewMenu = navigationViewController.viewControllers[0] as DeckViewMenu
            let nameOfDeck = currentDeckName
            deckViewMenu.currentDeckName = nameOfDeck
        }
        if segue.identifier == "DeckTestSegue" {
            let navigationViewController: DeckTestNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as DeckTestNavigationController
            let deckTestMenu: DeckTestMenu = navigationViewController.viewControllers[0] as DeckTestMenu
            let nameOfDeck = currentDeckName
            deckTestMenu.currentDeckName = nameOfDeck
            println("DeckTestSegue Success")
        }
}
```

When recompiled and the second segue is clicked then the program crashes and the console just has a (lldb) error with no other information.

Comment: Put a break point and check in which line program is crashing

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I think that the following code causes the crash.

```
let deckTestMenu: DeckTestMenu = navigationViewController.viewControllers[0] as DeckTestMenu
```

In your question you are telling that the first segue is working. In that code you written like:

```
let deckViewMenu: DeckViewMenu = navigationViewController.viewControllers[0] as DeckViewMenu
```

If that worked then the second casting will fail because `navigationViewController.viewControllers[0]` is a instance of `DeckViewMenu` not `DeckTestMenu`.

Comment: Even after changing the variable I still get the same error any suggestions?

Comment: @user3529361: Can you tell me what is the new code there ?

Comment: I changed the variable name: `let deckTestMenu: DeckTestMenu = deckTestNavigationController.viewControllers[0] as DeckTestMenu`

Comment: After some break points I think it is the assignment of the deckTestMenu variable that is causing the program to crash but I can't figure out the reason

Comment: @user3529361: That reason is I put in my answer, changing the variable name doesn't change anything. Read the answer once again.

Comment: I created two instances of the destinationViewController:

The first if statement:
`let deckViewNavigationController: DeckViewNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as DeckViewNavigationController
// then same code`

Second if statement:

`let deckTestNavigationController: DeckTestNavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as DeckTestNavigationController
//Then same code`

Comment: Ahh don't worry I got it sorted out!